# primeng dropdown not displaying values

Tags: angular, label, dropdown, primeng

Is it necessary to map to labels and values in order to show values on dropdown ?

I'm trying to show enums on my dropdown but they are not displaying correctly !

```
  export enum nature
    {
        annuelle="Annuelle",
        semestrielle="Semestrielle",
        trimestrielle="Trimestrielle"

    }
```

```
 naturevalues = Object.values(nature);
```

```
 <div class="ui-grid-col-6">
                    <p-dropdown [options]="naturevalues"  formControlName="nature"></p-dropdown>
                </div>
```

[image: this is the list]
I can see the chosen value on the console
[image: i can see the chosen value on the console]
I tried to add optionLabel="value" but in vain

Comment: you need to set like     {label: '', value: ''},

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-hgjiej) set to primeng options this

```
 naturevalues =   Object.keys(nature).map(key => ({ label: nature[key], value: key }));
```

Comment: but i don't want to turn my variable nature into an array of labels and values , i want to get the value directly like in the screenshot above , is it possible ?

Comment: You can do it with custome template inside pdropdown

Comment: But in this situation you may have several problems such as to see selected item. So I suggest you to use label value and with onchange method assing your  wanted output tipe with mapping. One single selected its output is string You can check in demo

Answer (score 5):

For those who come here from Google:

**nature.enum.ts**

```
export enum Nature {
   annuelle = "Annuelle",
   semestrielle = "Semestrielle",
   trimestrielle = "Trimestrielle"
}
```

In **component.ts:** define a list, where `Nature` is just an imported enum:

```
import {Nature} from 'enums/nature.enum';
//other imports

  public natures = Nature;
```

And in your template use `keyvalue` pipe and set `optionLabel` to `value`:

```
<div class="ui-grid-col-6">
    <p-dropdown [options]="natures | keyvalue" optionLabel="value" formControlName="nature"></p-dropdown>
</div>
```